# join two tables taking the one with max value

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I'd like to join two table in a one-to-many relationship, but selecting only one row in the second table, the one with a max value at a column X of the second table.

Here is the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6f81a/24).

Here's my first solution:

```
select u.*, a.id, a.address 
from my_user u 
inner join my_address a on u.username = a.username
where a.id = (
  select max(id) from my_address a where a.username = u.username
);
```

Here's the second solution:

```
select * from (
  select 
    u.username, u.name, u.surname, a.id, a.address,
    row_number() over (partition by a.username order by a.id desc) rn
  from my_user u 
  inner join my_address a on u.username = a.username
) res 
where rn = 1;
```

Can you spot me the differences? Which is the best way and why? Are there any other better solutions?

Thanks!!

Comment: Have you compared their explain plans? Any difference? (I'd guess query 2 performs better.)

Comment: Are both working or is there an issue with them? This isn't a code review site so please be a little more specific in what you are asking.

Comment: no issues, I was wondering which are the differences in terms of performance and cost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both your queries are okay for the task. None is really better than the other. But one may be faster than the other, which you can find out with `EXPLAIN PLAN`. Ideally Oracle would come up with the same execution plan for both, but it's a hard task for the optimizer to detect that both queries do the same thing.

As of Oracle 12c I'd use `CROSS APPLY`:

```
select u.*, a.id, a.address 
from my_user u
cross apply
(
  select *
  from my_address ma
  where ma.username = u.username
  order by ma.id desc
  fetch first row only
) a;
```

In earlier versions (as of Oracle 9i):

```
select u.*, a.id, a.address 
from my_user u
join
(
  select ma.*, row_number() over (partition by username order by id desc) as rn
  from my_address ma
) a on a.username = u.username and a.rn = 1;
```

In even earlier versions:

```
select u.*, a.id, a.address 
from my_user u
join
(
  select *
  from my_address ma
  where id in (select max(id) from my_address group by username)
) a on a.username = u.username;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c0d3ab6617956cb69f979a413026f6db